# Inheritance of non-list based classes in R?

Tags: r, oop, inheritance

In R inheritance can be implemented by extending a list based class the following way: 
Assume `lmo` is a object of class `lm` obtained from linear model fitting. The class could simply be extended by:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rexp(1000)
lmo <- lm(x~y)

lmo$addition <- "some more information"
class(lmo) <- c("lmext","lm")
```

I could still use all methods like `summary.lm` that worked for `lm` but also defined custom methods. Obviously there are lots of situations in which you want to just have minimal additions and still want to be able to use all the methods from the parent class.

What is the best way to add additional properties and implement method inheritance for classes that are not based on lists like e.g. time series? 
Here's what I could imagine:

```
ts1 <- ts(rnorm(100),start = c(1990,1),frequency = 4)
attr(ts1,"additional") <- "some more information"
class(ts1) <- c("tsext","ts")

print.tsext <- 
# some method that uses the original print method for ts, plus extracts
# the additional information
```

Is this a good way of achieving that operators like `+` etc. still work without redefining everything for the new class? Is there something better? And is there a way of keeping the additional class / attributes when for example adding two series to each other without redefining all the basic operators?

Comment: There is nothing special about inheriting from lists.  Inheritance for S3 classes work as you describe.  Because of this inheritance, the methods for your parent classes will be available.  However, as you point out, the parent class methods may not keep your new attributes intact.  In this case you may have to redefine all methods that affect your attributes.  At least, I don't know of a different way of doing this.

Comment: @Andrie thanks for the insight. Though there is indeed nothing special about lists, the difference is that it's easier to keep list elements than attributes – at least from what I tried. Particularly redefining all the operators seems cumbersome to me. Not exactly encouraging that a more experienced user like you does not see a different way...

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping additional class attributes" in case of adding two objects? R can't know what you want to do with the additional attributes when adding. You will have to overwrite the operators. But you can shorten your code via "Ops", e.g. to replace all 2-ary operators you can use `"Ops.MyNewClass" <- function(e1, e2) { atts <- MakeAttributes(e1, e2); res <- NextMethod(e1, e2); res <- AddAttributes(res, atts); res }` where NextMethod invokes the usual addition/subtraction/etc for the parent class.

Comment: @PatrickRoocks very cool. I was just hoping for hints like this. I hadn't heard about the `Ops` to access all the 2-ary operators. Where did you learn that? Maybe that's just the specific help document I didn't read.

Comment: Actually I don't know where I saw this first. I asked a [question about operator overloading for functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432273/operator-overloading-for-functions-in-r-strange-behavior) some time ago, where I got some hints about this. Probably I saw some example code with "Ops" when googling around... `?S3groupGeneric` and `?S4groupGeneric` tells us something about the mechanisms, but the examples there are not really helpful :-/

Comment: eh, are there other groups of methods and function like `Ops` that help to bulk-overwrite all/several methods, e.g. plot/summary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem with basic functions dropping additional S3 classes:

```
> foo=1:10
> class(foo)
[1] "integer"
> class(foo)=c("thing","integer")
> class(foo[1:4])
[1] "integer"
```

But how does `Date` get round this?

```
> dv = as.Date(c("2013-01-01","2013-02-02","2013-02-02","2013-02-06"))
> class(dv)
[1] "Date"
> class(dv[2:3])
[1] "Date"
```

BY redefining `[` for the `Date` class of course:

```
> get("[.Date")
function (x, ..., drop = TRUE) 
{
    cl <- oldClass(x)
    class(x) <- NULL
    val <- NextMethod("[")
    class(val) <- cl
    val
}
```

You might notice that this method doesn't actually mention `Date` in its code at all - it just gets the old class, calls the default subscript method, then reassigns the original class. Quite why this isn't the default behaviour is a mystery, but it does mean that if you want to create a new class based on vectors you can just copy this function as your new subset method.

*That's the simplest example I know of a problem creating subclasses in R. The rest of this answer will show some more perils, and I will try not to get too ranty in the process. I think this is all pertinent to your question.*

But sadly non-base classes get abused *A LOT* in R code, and you'll end up having to write a bunch of other fairly "generic" methods to make your class work:

```
> d = data.frame(f=foo,x=1:10)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""thing"" to a data.frame
```

so now you have to write `as.data.frame.thing`, which fortunately can be the same as `as.data.frame.Date`

```
> as.data.frame.thing = as.data.frame.Date
> d = data.frame(f=foo,x=1:10)
> d
```

Great, so now you've got your `thing` class in a data frame.

Then one day you'll try and do something with `dplyr` using a vector of your class in a data frame and you get spat at:

```
> d %.% group_by(f) %.% summarise(m=mean(x))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : column 'f' has unsupported type
```

But `dplyr` works with `Date` objects right? That's because deep on the C++ code, it checks for `Date` types. At this point you despair.

These are just some of the pitfalls of writing S3 classes that inherit from existing classes. Basically, stuff **doesnt** just work, at least not in the way you might expect if you have experience in OOP in another language.